# get "app name" on facebook timeline when publishing action

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

So I wanted to have something like in this [image](https://skitch.com/pekpongpaet/89amt/first-time-ever). Basically you have a "Get app name" when you publish your action. How do you do this using the facebook-ios-sdk? What open graph settings that you need to set in order to have this appear on your timeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called `Action links`. You can set action links to any post.

```
NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary 
  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"text here",@"text",@"link here",
                                @"href", nil], nil];

  NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

  NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary
                                 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                 actionLinksStr, @"action_links",

                                 nil];
```

> Open Graph Actions are the high-level "interactions" users can perform
>   in your app. When these actions are published, the activities may
>   appear in a users' Timeline or their friends' News Feeds and Ticker.
>   Open Graph Action Links show up alongside the Like and Comment actions
>   in any Open Graph story allowing friends to quickly take action in
>   response to a story without having to navigate away from that story.
>   This in turn will drive more distribution to your app with fewer user
>   clicks.

FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/